# why unity post processing effect not work in webgl?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, post-processing, bloom

Everything is perfect in editor. bloom、mothionblur.. but when i built project into webgl and play in chrome no bloom effect at all.
i'm using Built-in render pipeline and linear color space . even manual setting graphic apis to webgl 2.0 but no luck.
please help me with that.

here is the setting
[player setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fc6x.png)

[quality setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ommbm.png)

[effect in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkZ12.png)
[effect in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ9UP.png)

Comment: HDR is not support in built-in pipeline . so,try urp or hdrp fix that problem. hopes it helps for someone who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to enable HDR for your quality level as it is described [here](https://foxxthom.medium.com/post-processing-not-showing-in-webgl-builds-9290e581f5d7).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have read this post before. But i 'm using the Built-in RenderPipeline. It seems to be URP in the post . Sorry, i just learn Unity3d ,where I can find this settings?